# Django reverse foreignkey query in template using _set

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Dear Stack community.

given my simplified models:

```
* classes:
   name_id;
   description;
* architectures: 
   name_id;
   description;
* families:
   name_id;
   description;
   architecture = foreignKey(architectures);
   class = foreignKey(classes);
```

I'm trying to get from a query defined in views.py as:

```
query = classes.objects.all()
return(query)
```

the number of architectures entry related to it in templates.

```
{% for obj in query %}
Class {{ obj.name_id }} has {{ obj.families_set.all.architecture.count }} architectures.  
{% endfor %}
```

But nothing is shown.

If I try to do `{{ obj.families_set.all.count}}` I have all the number of families in the class. 
If I try to do `{{ obj.families_set.all.o.architecture.name_id }}` I get the first name of architecture that belongs to the class.

Can someone help? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `..._set.all` returns a queryset not a single object. The queryset does not have an `architecture` field, it's the objects in the queryset that do. Better to do an aggregation with `Count` in your view and pass that to the template.

Comment: Thank you, Moses, but I would really like to resolve this in templates; also because I don't get how to count these elements in views and then pass them into template maintaining an association with " classes ".